# plotting two functions on the same trendline in matlab

Tags: matlab

This is my original code:

```
function a = graph_times()
merge_times = [];
for i = 100:100:1000
    curr = sort_timer(i);
    merge_times = [merge_times, curr(1)];
end
plot(100:100:1000, merge_times);

a = 1;
end
```

I want to modify this code so that it plots trendlines for both `insertion_sort` and `merge_sort` on the same graph.
Below are the functions for `merge_sort` and `insertion_sort`

```
function c = insertion_sort(list1)
inserted = [];
for i = 1:size(list1,2)
inserted = insert_in_order(inserted,list1(1,i))
c = inserted
end
steps2=0;

function b = merge_sort(nums)
    if size(nums,2) == 1
        b = nums;
        return;
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give several sets of coordinates to MATLAB's `plot` function. You can plot the times of the two sorting algorithms like so:

```
plot(100:100:1000, merge_times, 100:100:1000, insertion_times);
```